# grpc_tools.protoc -> 'Could not make proto path relative'

Tags: python, grpc, protoc, grpc-python

I want to generate protobuf (pb2) files for Python programmatically using `grpc_tools`.

With this layout (potentially other languages in parallel to 'python/')

```
+---gen
+---protos
|       phone.proto
|
\---python
        call_protoc.py
```

this installation in a (Windows) Python 3.9.5 `venv`

```
grpcio==1.38.0
grpcio-tools==1.38.0
protobuf==3.17.0
```

and this very short `call_protoc.py`

```
from grpc_tools import protoc

protoc.main('--proto_path=../protos --python_out=../gen --grpc_python_out=../gen phone.proto'.split())
```

calling in ./python
(no separate `protoc` installation)

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=../protos --python_out=../gen --grpc_python_out=../gen phone.proto
```

generates

```
+---gen
    phone_pb2.py
    phone_pb2_grpc.py
```

but calling (same directory, same parameters)

```
python call_protoc.py
```

tells:
**Could not make proto path relative: phone.proto: No such file or directory**

From looking into the implementation I found it prepends sys.argv[0] and appends a `-I<site-packages>/grpc_tools/_proto.py`.
There is no reason given for these extra parameters.

So I need to **prepend *any* single parameter**, then `protoc.main()` works as expected

```
from grpc_tools import protoc

protoc.main('foo_or_just_a_dot --proto_path=../protos --python_out=../gen --grpc_python_out=../gen phone.proto'.split())
```

Did I miss something in the documentation of `grpc_tools.protoc.main()`?

Shouldn't it work same as calling

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc <normal_protoc_arguments>
```

?

Comment: Can you try referencing your proto with its import path prefixed? i.e. `../protos/phone.proto`

Comment: Thanks for looking into that, but this path for the proto is given already with ``--proto_path=`` (aka ``-I``).
So this does not remove the need for the strange leading extra (dummy) parameter, like just a dot.
(I provided all information, besides I used for this minimal example this proto:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/async_streaming/phone.proto
but this does not matter for the question.)

I would expect ``protoc.main()`` should be called with the same parameters as ``python -m grpc_tools.protoc`` (or protoc, which I did not install).

Comment: Thanks for asking and providing the workaround with the arbitrary single parameter, made my day.